# Simple mde editor

Tags: javascript, jquery, markdown

I am trying to add markdown editor with my application. i tried with simplemd-editor found from https://github.com/NextStepWebs/simplemde-markdown-editor ;
It is working fine whereas it changes the cursor pointer of my texarea 
as shown in the picture below
 [image].

And when typing, text coming with some background color as shown in below picture;
[image]

Question:
 My textarea cursor should not be changed (it should appear with basic style) and background color should not appear when typing. Please help how to achieve this using jquery?

Comment: Show initialization code please

Comment: var simplemde = new SimpleMDE({ element: document.getElementById("ta_add_notes"),styleSelectedText: false });   //ta_add_notes is my textarea ..

Comment: Hm, that thing with cursor is it happens in all web browsers? About background color, maybe you override default css? Would be great if you provide an example of your error in jsfiddle

Answer (score 2):

The background color is occurring because of the integrated spell check. You need to initialize your SimpleMDE with spell check disabled, like this:

`var simplemde = new SimpleMDE({
    spellChecker: false
});`

Reference: [SimpleMDE Configuration](https://github.com/sparksuite/simplemde-markdown-editor/blob/master/README.md#configuration)

Answer (score 0):

For future references, I fixed this problem by adding

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
```

In my html file

See [this github issue](https://github.com/codemirror/CodeMirror/issues/2276)